# map a stream to lazy promise stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bacon.js

I have a I have a stream of numbers, I have to turn them into a stream of posts using a promise. And I want to do this lazily. So if I do `.take(1)` from the post stream, it will turn only one number to a post.

This is the promise that gets a post from a number:

```
var getPost = function(author) {
  console.log('get post' + author);
  return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var result = "Post by " + author;
      resolve(result);
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

I am only interested in first post, thus `take(1)`, and It should call `getPost` once.

If I use `map`, the stream works lazy, calls `getPost` once. If I use `flatmap`, it calls `getPost` for all the numbers.

```
var lazyStream = Bacon.fromArray([1, 2, 3, 4]).map(function(value) {
  return Bacon.fromPromise(getPost(value));
});

var nonLazyStream = Bacon.fromArray([1, 2, 3, 4]).flatMap(function(value) {
  return Bacon.fromPromise(getPost(value));
});

lazyStream.take(2).log();
//nonLazyStream.take(2).log();
```

However `map` returns a promise, while `flatMap` returns the post itself. How do I have a lazy stream that returns the value of promise?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, thanks so much, that works, I am confused how/why this works, an explanation and/or an alternative better solution will be accepted. Because it looks to me like `flatMapWithConcurrencyLimit` is a side effect that solves this problem.

Comment: I've added more details, let me know if it is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`flatMap`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#observable-flatmap) takes all the streams created by the promises at once and spawns a new stream using all of the streams at once. Live you have observed this is not lazy and will call all the promise returning functions at once.

You want that to happen one at a time so you should use [`flatMapConcat`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#observable-flatmapconcat). Instead of taking all the streams at once it will call them one at a time invoking the promises one by one - this is what you'd normally expect `.flatMap` to do in some other FRP libraries. Note that this generalizes using [`flatMapWithConcurrencyLimit`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#observable-flatmapwithconcurrencylimit) if you ever need it to do `n` at a time.

Here is an example using [`flatMapConcat`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#observable-flatmapconcat) for a similar case:

```
function delayPromise(val){ // delayed promise simulating an async request
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Resolve timeout"); resolve(val); }, 500);  
    });
}

var stream = Bacon.fromArray([1, 2, 3, 4]).flatMapConcat(function(value) {
  return Bacon.fromPromise(delayPromise(value));
});

stream.take(1).log();
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2bjoqzvq/)